# Delegateをtimer処理で使うには？

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

画面遷移先でユーザーがタイマーを設定し、そのタイマーを画面遷移する前の元の`ViewController`で作動させるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？`func prepare`で値を受け渡してタイマーを作動させようとしてみたのですが、エラーはないもののうまくいかず、`protocol`を使うのかなと思っているのですが、これも実装の順番や方法がイマイチわかりません。
以下、私が試してみたコードを抜粋して載せます。解決策を教えてくだされば幸いです。

```
//class FirstViewController
//whatToDoLbl: UILabel!,taskUnSetted: UILabel!,taskContent: UILabel!
//var timer = Timer()
//var count: Int = 0
    @IBAction func unwindToFirstView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "backToFVCSet"
        {
            let EditPopUpVC = segue.destination as! EditPopUpViewController
            if EditPopUpVC.doneOutlet.isHidden == false
            {
                whatToDoLbl = EditPopUpVC.whatToDoLblAtEditVC
                taskUnSetted = EditPopUpVC.taskUnSettedAtEditVC

                whatToDoLbl.isHidden = false
                taskUnSetted.isHidden = true
                taskContent.isHidden = false

                count = EditPopUpVC.countAtEditVC
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(FirstViewController.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)     
            }
        }
    }

    func counter()
    {
        let leftHours = Int(count/3600)
        let leftMinutes = Int((count - leftHours * 3600)/60)
        let leftSeconds = count % 60

        let hh = NSString(format: "%02d", leftHours)
        let mm = NSString(format: "%02d", leftMinutes)
        let ss = NSString(format: "%02d", leftSeconds)
        if count > 0
        {
            taskContent.text = "\(hh)時間 \(mm)分 \(ss)秒"
        }
        else
        {
            taskContent.text = "終了!"
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
```

以下サブクラスです。（画面遷移先）

```
class EditPopUpViewController: ・・・{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //略
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        //略
    }
    @IBAction func closePopUp(_ sender: Any)//完了ボタン
    {
        //var countAtEditVC = 0
        //@IBOutlet weak var wheelTimerOutlet: UIDatePicker!
        countAtEditVC = Int(wheelTimerOutlet.countDownDuration)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

コードに関してご不明な点・不明瞭な点があればお伝えいただけると嬉しいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `FirstViewController`の変数（おそらくプロパティ？）の`count`と`timer`が唐突に登場していて、宣言部の説明も提示もないのが、違和感を与えます。提示コードの修正をお願いしていいですか？

Comment: @nagonsoftware 申し訳有りません。只今修正しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問の内容に即していうなら、画面遷移時のデータの受け渡しを、Delegateを用いて行う処理に関することになります。Delegateの実装にプロトコルを用いますが、プロトコルが主題にはならないので、勝手ながら、質問のタイトルを編集させていただきました。
画面遷移時にDelegateによって、データを受け渡すのは、定石の処理ですが、Storyboard登場以降は、レガシーな定石となってしまいました。Unwind Segueを用いて、データを受け渡すのが、今流のやり方なので、まずそちらの解説をし、次にレガシーなDelegateによるデータの受け渡しを説明します。

---

まず、Unwind SegueをStoryboardで設定する手順を説明します。モーダル表示の`ModalViewController`から`ViewController`に戻るものとします。
`ViewController`にアクションメソッド`unwindAction(_:)`を定義します。引数の型を`UIStoryboardSegue`にします。
Storyboardで、`ModalViewController`から、Exitにコネクトします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
Document Outlineに、Unwind Segueができているので、それを選択し、Attributes Inspectorを編集します。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
Unwind SegueのIdentifierを`Unwind`とします。
`ModalViewController`を実装します。

```
import UIKit

class ModalViewController: UIViewController {

    // カウントダウンの時間
    var timerInterval: TimeInterval = 0.0

    // カウントダウンタイム設定のUIDatePicker
    @IBOutlet weak var countDownPicker: UIDatePicker!

    // モーダル終了をするボタンのアクションメソッド
    @IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        timerInterval = countDownPicker.countDownDuration
        // Unwind Segueを実行する。
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Unwind", sender: self)
    }

}
```

StoryboardSegueをコードで実行するために、メソッド`performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?)`が用意されていることを、これを機会に覚えてください。
次に、`ViewController`の実装を行います。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // カウントダウンの時間。TimeInterval型ではなくて、Date型にしている点に注意。
    var countDownDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0.0)

    // カウントダウン時間を表示するラベル。
    @IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!

    // Unwindした時に呼ばれるメソッド
    @IBAction func unwindAction(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        // 遷移元の取得に失敗したら、何もしない。
        guard let controller = segue.source as? ModalViewController else {
            return
        }

        // ModanViewControllerのプロパティtimerIntervalを、countDownDateに受け渡す。
        countDownDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: controller.timerInterval)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH時間mm分ss秒"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
        countDownLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: countDownDate)
        // タイマー開始。
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.countDown(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    // Timerが実行するメソッド。引数にTimer型を取ると、Timerをプロパティにする必要がなくなる。
    func countDown(_ timer: Timer) {
        countDownDate -= 1.0 // Date型で使用可能な、特別な演算子
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH時間mm分ss秒"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
        countDownLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: countDownDate)

        // カウントダウンが終わったら、タイマー終了する。
        if countDownDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate <= 0.0 {
            timer.invalidate()
            countDownLabel.text = "終了"
        }
    }

}
```

上のコードでは、`DateFormatter`を用いて、時間の定型表示を行なっています。こんなやり方もあるのだなくらいに受け取ってください。こうしなければいけないといっているわけではありません。

---

Delegateを使った、画面遷移時のデータの受け渡しを説明します。Unwind Segueを使った処理の方が、圧倒的に簡潔で、わかりやすいことが明白です。
まず、`ModalViewController`の実装です。

```
import UIKit

class ModalViewController: UIViewController {

    // Delegateを記憶させるプロパティ。型がプロトコルで、かつオプショナル型、そしてweak属性がついている点に注目。
    weak var delegate: ModalDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var countDownPicker: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        // delegateがnilだったら、何もしない。
        guard let delegate = delegate else {
            return
        }

        // ViewControllerのメソッドsetTimer(interval:)を呼ぶ。
        delegate.setTimer(interval: countDownPicker.countDownDuration)
        // モーダルを閉じる。
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

// プロトコルModalDelegateの定義
protocol ModalDelegate: class {
    func setTimer(interval: TimeInterval)
}

// ViewControllerが、メソッドsetTimer(interval:)を定義していない場合の処理。
extension ModalDelegate {
    func setTimer(interval: TimeInterval) {
        print("Delegate is not defined.")
    }
}
```

プロトコルの定義のために、Swiftファイルをひとつ作る必要はなく、ひとつのSwiftファイルにまとめて書いておくことができます。
次に、`ViewController`のコードを編集します。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ModalDelegate {

    var timerDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0.0)

    @IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!

    // ViewControllerからModalViewControllerに遷移するタイミングで、ModalViewControllerのプロパティdelegateに、selfを代入。
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let controller = segue.destination as? ModalViewController {
            controller.delegate = self
        }
    }

    // Delegateメソッド
    func setTimer(interval: TimeInterval) {
        timerDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: interval)
        let format = DateFormatter()
        format.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
        format.dateFormat = "HH時間mm分ss秒"
        countDownLabel.text = format.string(from: timerDate)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.countDown(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func countDown(_ timer: Timer) {
        timerDate -= 1.0
        let format = DateFormatter()
        format.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
        format.dateFormat = "HH時間mm分ss秒"
        countDownLabel.text = format.string(from: timerDate)

        if timerDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate <= 0.0 {
            timer.invalidate()
            countDownLabel.text = "終了"
        }
    }

}
```

以上が、Delegateの典型的な定型処理です。このパターンを覚えておけば、ほかのDelegate処理に容易に応用できます。ただし、今流で行くなら、クロージャを使った処理の方が多いとは思います。

Comment: やり方を複数ご提示してくださり、丁寧なご説明までしてくださってありがとうございました。本当に助かりました。